# Merge One Sveltekit App into another Sveltekit App

Tags: compiler-construction, load, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I have two Sveltekit apps.
A. Is a normal website app
B. Exists inside electron

I want A the normal Sveltekit website, to import B Sveltekit app running in electron.
Why? so any changes I make to electron app automatically syncs to web app and I don't need to manually update src folders in A.

In order for Sveltekit to compile correctly, it seems all files need to be in the src directory. I can place B, electron app, inside A, web apps src folder and it works. It compiles correctly when built and works great. However, On Localhost it takes 1 minute to spin up and I think its because localhost tries to load everything included in electron and that makes editing the website terrible and bloated with unnecessary files.
I also tried syncing two folders in the operating system but on mac it seems impractical.

The performance suffers. Can I import a precompiled version of the electron app into the website through some server load function? Sveltekit and Vites backend system gets pretty hairy so any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer to this question as it depends on what you do with your electron app however it can be put into three categories:

---

##### 1. Port to sveltekit and run like that. (do you need electron?)

Remove electron overhead and port to sveltekit and run from web.

##### 2. If you are already using a sveltekit + electron template or adapter

eg. https://github.com/ptkdev/sveltekit-electron-adapter

You can use that to run your electron app and prerender the site (eg. static)

Or build up the code with a different template.

##### 3. Split the code or port to a template

If you need both electron and webapp split your code into svelte components that can be interchanged on build/runtime so you have your sveltekit package for web and electron package.

The electron/desktop reliant components are not included/rewritten or disabled for web and vice-versa.

Other components that can be interchanged/are both compatible with svelte and electron can be kept as is. Keep your main files as broad as possible and build both web and electron.

Something like:
https://github.com/FractalHQ/sveltekit-electron

---

Or lastly port to sveltekit, have your electron app spin up a server
like with:

```
npm run dev
```

then point to it.

For that use `<webview>` or BrowserView

[browser view example](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-view):

```
// In the main process.
const { app, BrowserView, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })

  const view = new BrowserView()
  win.setBrowserView(view)
  view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300 })
  view.webContents.loadURL('https://electronjs.org')
})
```